# Problem running ROS2 Foxy Demo on MacOS

Tags: ros, ros2, macbook

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install ROS 2 on my Mac with this tutorial: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/macOS-Install-Binary.html

MacOS: Big Sur 11.5.2
ROS2 Foxy Patch Release 4

When I execute:

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

I get this RCL error:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError: failed to initialize rcl init options: failed to load shared library of rmw implementation: /Users/nayanpradhan/ros2_foxy/ros2-osx/lib/librmw_fastrtps_cpp.dylib Exception: LoadLibrary error: dlopen(/Users/nayanpradhan/ros2_foxy/ros2-osx/lib/librmw_fastrtps_cpp.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tinyxml2/lib/libtinyxml2.8.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/nayanpradhan/ros2_foxy/ros2-osx/lib/librmw_fastrtps_cpp.dylib Reason: image not found, at /Users/osrf/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_osx/ws/src/ros2/rcutils/src/shared_library.c:84, at /Users/osrf/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_osx/ws/src/ros2/rmw_implementation/rmw_implementation/src/functions.cpp:64, at /Users/osrf/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_osx/ws/src/ros2/rcl/rcl/src/rcl/init_options.c:61
```

In general, sourcing also gives the warning:

```
[connext_cmake_module] Warning: The location at which Connext was found when the workspace was built [[/Applications/rti_connext_dds-5.3.1]] does not point to a valid directory, and the NDDSHOME environment variable has not been set. Support for Connext will not be available.
```

How can I fix these errors/warning???

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384850/problem-running-ros2-foxy-demo-on-macos/) by [nayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/79277/nayan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-08-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [victra](https://answers.ros.org/users/86473/victra/) on 2021-10-05**:
Hey Nayan, did you manage to solve this problem? I have the same problem myself

**Comment by [Sensenzhl](https://answers.ros.org/users/91351/sensenzhl/) on 2021-12-10**:
I meet this problem too. Is there any available solution right now?

**Comment by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) on 2021-12-23**:
@Sensenzhl, were you able to get ROS2 working on macOS?

**Comment by [Sensenzhl](https://answers.ros.org/users/91351/sensenzhl/) on 2022-01-01**:
I have installed ROS2 working, but still leave this problem unsolved

**Comment by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) on 2022-01-04**:
My conclusion is to run Ubuntu on a USB stick and call it a day. At the time of this writing, ROS supports macOS Mojave, which was released in 2018. Now it is 2022. So, it is not worth forcing ROS to run on macOS.

**Comment by [Sensenzhl](https://answers.ros.org/users/91351/sensenzhl/) on 2022-01-04**:
Thanks for your reply. I've tried the method you mentioned that downgrading tinyxml2 to 2.8. The version I use now is tinyxml2 version 2.9. But it seems that tinyxml2.8 is not compatible with macOS Big Sur, it can only be used on macOS Catalina. Is there any method to deal with this?

**Comment by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) on 2022-01-05**:
My conclusion is that it is too tedious on macOS to ensure that all packages are the proper versions. I suggest using Ubuntu instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you try `. ~/ros2_foxy/ros2-osx/setup.bash` before you test that one?

If so, try to re-install and be sure you are on foxy

Updated (1/18/22):
Answered by @chrisfromsoftware

Answer:
Same problem for me as well, on macOS Mojave. I resolved my problem by following this example and downgrading my tinyxml2 to 2.8: https://gist.github.com/talal/1b8d0c11338dc9ab79b2386309828894

The git hash I used for the formula was: 1592a31d0be73d01943e729d98aab4e494ca4351

---

Originally posted by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) with karma: 113 on 2021-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) on 2021-12-23**:
I have the same issue as @nayan. And yes, I ran `. ~/ros2_foxy/ros2-osx/setup.bash`. If you look carefully at the error, you see that it is trying to load tinyxml2 version 2.8, which does not install when you follow the steps specified on `https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/macOS-Install-Binary.html`. If you look in that directory, as of December 2021, you will see that tinyxml2 version 2.9 is installed. (I am on macOS 12.1 Monterrey.)

**Comment by [chrisfromsoftware](https://answers.ros.org/users/92056/chrisfromsoftware/) on 2021-12-23**:
Same problem for me as well, on macOS Mojave.  I resolved my problem by following this example and downgrading my tinyxml2 to 2.8:  https://gist.github.com/talal/1b8d0c11338dc9ab79b2386309828894

The git hash I used for the formula was:  1592a31d0be73d01943e729d98aab4e494ca4351

**Comment by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) on 2021-12-25**:
I see in the ROS documentation that they are supporting macOS Mojave. But Mojave is just over 3 years old. What is the motivation to keep legacy OS?

**Comment by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) on 2021-12-28**:
Thanks @chrisfromsoftware. Downgrading tinyxml2 to 2.8 worked. Maybe you should post this as an answer!

**Comment by [Karax](https://answers.ros.org/users/37470/karax/) on 2022-01-18**:
[@chrisfromsoftware](https://answers.ros.org/users/92056/chrisfromsoftware/) tip did the trick for me too. Currently running on macOS Monterey 12.1 (Intel).

**Comment by [Zeitgeist](https://answers.ros.org/users/101192/zeitgeist/) on 2022-04-05**:
@Karax Can you please help with this? I have the same hardware. But i steel not understand how we need change this https://gist.github.com/talal/1b8d0c11338dc9ab79b2386309828894 to downgrading tinyxml2 to 2.8. Can you please describe it in details. Thanks.

**Comment by [märve](https://answers.ros.org/users/102152/m%C3%A4rve/) on 2022-04-15**:
@Zeitgeist here the steps to downgrade to 2.8

`cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)"`
`git checkout -b tinyxml2-2.8 1592a31d0be73d01943e729d98aab4e494ca4351`
`brew unlink tinyxml2`
`HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install tinyxml2`
`brew pin tinyxml2`
`git checkout master`
`git branch -d tinyxml2-2.8`
`brew cleanup && brew prune`